# PYTHON Django tag with dynamic variable

Tags: python, django, variables, tags, nvd3.js

i am displaying a multibarchart with django-nvd3. i get my data almost like in the example.
http://django-nvd3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes-doc/multi-bar-chart.html

```
view.py
...
return render_to_response('multibarchart.html', {'data': data, 'form': form})
```

my data is a dictionary with all the infomation for nvd3. the data comes from a database. the dictionary has data for several years which i want to access cooresponding to the selection of a select form.

```
data = {2014: {
          'charttype': charttype,
          'chartdata': chartdata},
        2015: {
          'charttype': charttype,
          'chartdata': chartdata}
        }
```

in the html i have a variable with the post from the selected year and i want to change the year nvd3 tag (here 2014).

```
{% include_container data.dict.**2014**.chart... 400 600 %}
```

i tried several things like ... {% with year as selected_year }}

```
{% include_container data.dict.{{ selected_year }}.chart... 400 600 %}
```

or

```
{% include_container data.dict.selected_year.chart... 400 600 %}
```

but i cant figure out how the year can be dynamic. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at the [source code](https://github.com/areski/django-nvd3/blob/develop/django_nvd3/templatetags/nvd3_tags.py). The template tag is expecting the name of the container. From what I can see from your code each time the user chooses a year in the form the page reloads.

So what I would do is in the view populate a variable "selected_chart" with the corresponding container name and pass it in the context.

```
return render_to_response('multibarchart.html', {'data': data, 'form': form, 'selected_chart': CONTAINER_NAME})
```

Then in the template you should have:

```
{% include_container selected_chart 400 600 %}
```

If you need to change the chart without reloading the page then you would need a different approach. Let me know if this is the case.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.